# How to Render Mobile Image Upload with Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am using Google Apps Script to take image data from a client side application and storing it in a Google Drive folder, as an image. The script works fine on a desktop, but when I attempt to use the script on mobile, only the top quarter or so of the image appears in the Google Drive folder. Any help on this?

Client Side JavaScript:

```
            //resizing file input
            function cropAndResizeImage(file, maxSize) {
                return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    loadImage.parseMetaData(file, function (data) {
                    const options = {
                        canvas: true,
                        orientation: true,
                    };

                    if (data.exif) {
                        options.orientation = data.exif.get('Orientation');
                    }

                    loadImage(file, (canvas) => {
                        if (canvas.type === "error") {
                        reject("Error loading image");
                        } else {
                        const minDimension = Math.min(canvas.width, canvas.height);
                        const offsetX = (canvas.width - minDimension) / 2;
                        const offsetY = (canvas.height - minDimension) / 2;
                        const croppedCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");

                        croppedCanvas.width = maxSize;
                        croppedCanvas.height = maxSize;

                        const croppedContext = croppedCanvas.getContext("2d");
                        croppedContext.drawImage(canvas, offsetX, offsetY, minDimension, minDimension, 0, 0, maxSize, maxSize);

                        resolve(croppedCanvas.toDataURL());
                        }
                    }, options);
                    });
                });
                }
```

HTML Library:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/blueimp-load-image/5.16.0/load-image.all.min.js"></script>
```

Apps Script Code:

```
function saveImageToDrive(base64Data, fileName) {
  const mimeType = base64Data.match(/data:([a-zA-Z0-9]+\/[a-zA-Z0-9-.+]+).*,.*/)[1];
  const fileData = Utilities.base64Decode(base64Data.split(",")[1]);
  const blob = Utilities.newBlob(fileData, mimeType, fileName);
  
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("FOLDER_ID_NAME"); // Replace with the ID of the folder you want to save the image to
  const file = folder.createFile(blob);

    // Set the file's sharing settings to public
  file.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE_WITH_LINK, DriveApp.Permission.VIEW);
  
  return file.getId(); // Returns the URL of the uploaded image
}
```

I am expecting the full image to be uploaded to the Google Drive Folder, yet when I use the script on mobile, only the top quarter of the image renders.